# MySQL5.7.26 round() function bug, how to fix it by SQL?

Tags: mysql, function, rounding

When I use round() function , it doesn't work in a case:

[image]

Comment: Welcome, to improve your experience on SO please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), 
 an [On Topic question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), 
 then look at the [Question Check list](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist), 
 [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/),
 how to create a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 and [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour)

Comment: It is often useful if you give us a little more than this to go on.

Comment: Like what did you expect `round(2.5)` to give you as a result

Comment: select round( cast((from_unixtime(1583173824,'%H')+from_unixtime(1583173824,'%i')/60) AS decimal(9,2)) );  ## I cast it to decimal and it work well now.

Answer (score 1):

This works as designed. `round()` returns the given argument rounded to the nearest value, according to the given precision.

So `2.5` (and everything above, up to `3.5` not included) gets rounded as `3`, while anything *stricly* smaller than `2.5` (and greater or equal than `1.5`) is rounded as `2`.

If you want the *integer* part of the number, you can use `floor()` instead: `floor(2.5)` gives you `2`.

Comment: The rounding rule depends on the type of the value. With decimals 2.5 is rounded up to 3, but with floats it depends on the underlying C library. Usually it gets rounded down so round(2.5) becomes 2.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> SELECT from_unixtime(1583173824,'%H') val1, 
>        from_unixtime(1583173824,'%i') val2,
>        from_unixtime(1583173824,'%H')+from_unixtime(1583173824,'%i')/60 val3,
>        round(from_unixtime(1583173824,'%H')+from_unixtime(1583173824,'%i')/60) val4,
>        round(CAST(from_unixtime(1583173824,'%H') AS DECIMAL(5,2))+from_unixtime(1583173824,'%i')/60) val5,
>        round(from_unixtime(1583173824,'%H')+CAST(from_unixtime(1583173824,'%i')/60 AS DECIMAL(5,2))) val6,
>        round(CAST(from_unixtime(1583173824,'%H') AS DECIMAL(5,2))+CAST(from_unixtime(1583173824,'%i')/60 AS DECIMAL(5,2))) val7,
>        round(CAST(from_unixtime(1583173824,'%H') AS DECIMAL(5,2))+CAST(from_unixtime(1583173824,'%i') AS DECIMAL(5,2))/60) val8
> ```
>
> ```
> val1 | val2 |    val3 | val4 | val5 | val6 | val7 | val8
> :--- | :--- | ------: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---: | ---:
> 18   | 30   | 18.5000 |   18 |   18 |   18 |   19 |   19
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=2cb3955c7a4ce38ef3bbf8090488dc6f)*

`from_unixtime` is used in numeric context - and the fiddle shows that its output datatype is floating-point.

Only explicit conversion to decimal datatype for both values causes server to perform the calculations in decimal, not real, context.